# Singleton in RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I want to make a simple singleton using RequireJS.

Something like this:

```
// js/modules/singleton.js
define([], function () {
    var Singleton = function() {
        this.value = 10;
    }
    return new Singleton();
 });
```

In my main entry I have the following code:

```
    // main.js
    require.config({
          paths: {
            singleton: 'js/modules/singleton'
          },
          shim: {

          }
    });

    var o1 = require(["singleton"]);  
    var o2 = require(["singleton"]);

console.log(o1 === o2);     // true
console.log(o1.value);      // undefined (?!)
console.log(o2.value);      // undefined (?!)

o1.value = 20;
console.log(o1.value);      // 20
console.log(o2.value);      // 20

o2.value = 30;
console.log(o1.value);      // 30
console.log(o2.value);      // 30
```

Variables o1 and o2 were correctly pointing to the same singleton instance (o1 === o2), but why are **o1.value** and **o2.value** undefined??

I would expect the attribute "value" to be =10 at this like, since it was so initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is pretty much a race condition.

A simple (synchronous!) call like

```
var o1 = require(["singleton"]);
```

returns the module just, if it has previously loaded using the asynchronous version of `require()`.

So to solve your problem, just wrap your code in a async `require()` call like this:

```
require( ['singleton'], function( singleton ){

    o1 = singleton;
    o2 = singleton;

    console.log(o1 === o2);     // true
    console.log(o1.value);      // 10
    console.log(o2.value);      // 10

    o1.value = 20;
    console.log(o1.value);      // 20
    console.log(o2.value);      // 20

    o2.value = 30;
    console.log(o1.value);      // 30
    console.log(o2.value);      // 30
});
```

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vtmbfzqn/)

> Citing the [RequireJS documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#modulenotes-console) (highlighting added):
>
> Console debugging: If you need to work with a module you already
>   loaded via a `require(["module/name"], function(){})` call in the
>   JavaScript console, then you can use the require() form that just uses
>   the string name of the module to fetch it:
>
> `require("module/name").callSomeFunction()`
>
> **Note this only works if "module/name" was previously loaded via the
>   async version of require**: `require(["module/name"])`. If using a
>   relative path, like './module/name', those only work inside define

Comment: I know I can do it that way but it is not acceptable in my case. I plan to load modules fully dinamically, "just in time", based on their ID (I have a lots of Singletones used in the same module and only few oof them are needed).

Comment: I don't see the problem right now. The only difference is async coding vs sync coding. For everything else, you can dynamically create the dependency list and grab the singletons using the `arguments` object.

Comment: Ok, I think I got something wrong... But if this is true "returns the module just, if it has previously loaded using the asynchronous version of require()", what is the purpose of this method?

Comment: You can use `require()` on NodeJS as well and there you have synchronous module loading, e.g. Also you can make sure in some ways, that the module has been loaded before and you just want another reference to it.